# Laravel extends class with constructor using DI

Tags: laravel, dependency-injection

I have created a small CRUD controller, I need to inject FormBuilder in the __construct() of this CRUD controller

```
class CrudController extends Controller
{
    private $formBuilder;

    /**
     * CrudController constructor.
     * @param FormBuilder $formBuilder
     */
    public function __construct(FormBuilder $formBuilder)
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->formBuilder = $formBuilder;
        // ....
```

My question is : can I extends this class without injecting `FormBuilder` to each child ? For now I have :

```
class LevelsCrudController extends CrudController
{
    public function __construct(FormBuilder $formBuilder)
    {
        parent::__construct($formBuilder);
        // .....
```

Which is really redondant, any workaround ?

Comment: Do you need to do anything in your `LevelsCrudController's` construct?

Comment: @ChinLeung yes, I set all the variable for the parent ($title, $uri ..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to have a `FormBuilder $formBuilder` in your child controller's construct, you could pass it as a param only when you call the parent's construct like this:

```
parent::__construct(resolve(FormBuilder::class));
```

Otherwise, you could remove it completely from the parent's constructor and resolve it inside the parent constructor like this:

```
class CrudController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->formBuilder = resolve(FormBuilder::class);

        // ...
    }
}
```

And then in your child, you can simple call:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Really nice answer, I am used to Symfony, I could inject through services.yaml, but in Laravel I didn't know. This is what I wanted, thanks